# Updating Binary File on Github using Contents API

Tags: python, github-api

After successfully updating a plain text file using the GitHub Repository Contents API, I tried to do the same thing with an Excel file. I understand that git isn't really designed to store binaries; however, this is what my client needs.

Here are the relevant lines of Python code:

```
# Get the XLSX file from the repo to get its SHA
g = GitHub(my_admin_token)
repo = g.get_repo("theowner/therepo")
contents = repo.get_contents("myfile.xlsx", ref="main")
sha = contents.sha

# So far, so good. We have the SHA.

# Read the bytes we want to use to replace the contents of the file
data = open('my_new_file.xlsx', 'rb').read()
base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(data)

# Update the XLSX file in the repo with the new bytes
result = repo.update_file(contents.path, "auto-committed", base64_encoded_data,
            sha, branch="main") 

print("Result of update_file:")
print(result)

# Result: {'commit': Commit(sha="88f46eb99ce6c1d7d7d287fb8913a7f92f6faeb2"), 'content': ContentFile(path="myfile.xlsx")}
```

Now, you'd think everything went well; however, when I go to GitHub and look at the file, it's a mass of Base64 encoded data. It somehow "loses the fact that it's an Excel file" in the translation. When I click on the file in the GitHub user interface, and I have the option to Download the file, I get the "big blob" of Base64 text vs. having the XLSX file download.

There doesn't seem to be a way to tell the API what encoding I want to use, e.g., there doesn't seem to be a way to set HTTP headers on the call.

I also tried using the Python *requests* library to *PUT* (per doc) to the GitHub API:

```
result = requests.put('https://api.github.com/repos/myname/myrepo/contents/myfile.xlsx', {
   "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw", 
      "Authorization": "token my_admin_token"
    },
    "committer": {'name':'My Name', 'email':'me@mymail.com'},
    "message": "Did it work?",
    "branch": "main",
    "content": base64_encoded_data})
```

and I get an HTTP *404.*

I tried playing with the *Accept* header types as well. No dice.

Various other issues trying this with *curl*.

If you have a working sample of updating/replacing an XLSX file on GitHub using curl, python, etc. I'd love to see it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a binary file is very much possible to GitHub. Both via `git` and via the GitHub API.

The following python snippet works as expected and uploads an excel file to a test repository at https://github.com/recycle-bin/github-playground/tree/main/hello . And I'm able to download the excel file as expected too.

```
import base64
import datetime
import os

import requests

github_token = os.environ["GITHUB_API_TOKEN"]
repository = "recycle-bin/github-playground"
xlsx_file_path = "workbook.xlsx"


def upload_file_to_github(source_file_path: str, destination_path: str):
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": f"token {github_token}",
        "accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
    }
    with open(source_file_path, "rb") as source_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(source_file.read()).decode("utf-8")

    payload = {
        "message": f"Uploaded file at {datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()}",
        "content": encoded_string,
    }

    requests.put(
        f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repository}/contents/{destination_path}",
        json=payload,
        headers=headers,
    )


def main():
    upload_file_to_github(xlsx_file_path, "hello/workbook.xlsx")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Your 404 could possibly be due to one of the following

1. The repository does not exist
2. The branch does not exist

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer the question. Your solution works for adding a new file to a new directory under the repository; however, it doesn't address replacing an existing XLSX with new content. That said, your solution prompted me to pursue the problem slightly differently, so I appreciate it.